# SQL: how to suggest likes with a relevance based on other users likes?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, algorithm, data-analysis

each user can add its **likes** with a **custom weight**.

> "I like bananas (7/10) and apples (10/10)"

I'd like to **suggest likes to users, based on what other users like**.

> "You like bananas. You might like apples as well."

The **SQL tables** have the following structure:

```
# users
- id
- ... 

# likes
- id
- label (e.g. "apple")
- ...

# user_likes
- id
- user_id
- like_id
- weight
```

The **desired output**:

```
# 1. Suggestions for user ("You probably like apples!")
| like_id | relevance |
-----------------------
| 5       |  0.5      |

# 2. Suggestions for like ("Apples fit to bananas!")
| like_id | relevance |
-----------------------
| 5       |  0.8      |
```

My current idea would be to loop all the records with PHP, but that can't be right.

Is there any best practise or algorithm for that? Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

**Important**: I found [this](http://webdam.inria.fr/Jorge/html/wdmch19.html) and other examples/duplicates to achieve what I need. This question might me detected as a duplicate, but I'm interested in the **latest best practice**. Many solutions are 10 years old.

Comment: Any chance you can provide an SQL fiddle with schema and sample data?

Comment: SQL fiddle for anyone else who wants to have a crack - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/866825/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will find all the likes of other users, who share one or more likes in common with a given user. It will then select the average like weight across those users to determine the relevancy of each like.

```
SELECT 
    l.*, AVG(ul_3.weight) AS weight
FROM 
    user_likes ul_1
INNER JOIN user_likes ul_2 
    ON ul_1.like_id = ul_2.like_id 
    AND ul_1.user_id <> ul_2.user_id
INNER JOIN user_likes ul_3 
    ON ul_2.user_id = ul_3.user_id
INNER JOIN likes l 
    ON l.id = ul_3.like_id
WHERE 
    ul_1.user_id = 5
    AND l.id <> ul_1.like_id
GROUP BY 
    l.id
ORDER BY
    weight DESC;
```

Working SQL fiddle with sample data - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/866825/2